# iOS app restarts in background on iOS 13.2.2 but not on iOS 12.4

Tags: ios, react-native

I am developing an iOS app in React Native. I have been testing my application on two iPhones - iPhone 6 running iOS `12.4` and iPhone 11 Pro Max running the latest - `13.2.2`.

I am having the strange problem that my application restarts when it is minimized in background and not used on the latest iOS. However, my app would continue from where it has been left after long periods of time on iOS `12.4` - in short it will not restart when in background, which is exactly what I want.

I wish to keep my app on the last state the user left it when navigating away from it, so the user can go back and continue their process. How can I fix this? How come an older iPhone with older hardware and older software manages to keep my application running in the background while the newest flagship with its latest software cannot manage it?

P.S. I had the same issue on one of the previous versions of iOS 13. I was really happy when I read that `13.2.2` [has addressed this issue](https://www.gsmarena.com/ios_1322_update_fixes_background_app_management_issue-news-40004.php) and I was hoping it would fix my problem. Unfortunately, it did not.

I would appreciate any ways and guides of debugging this problem and fixing it.

Comment: Look at your background resource usage.

Comment: You can never guarantee that iOS won't jettison your app once it is suspended if it needs resources. You should implement state restoration in your app so that when the user comes back, even if the app was relaunched, they can resume where they left off

Comment: @Paulw11 Of course that’s not so easy now that Apple has abandoned view controller based state saving and restoration (I know you know very well about that problem!).